# Java: Framework for Yahoo Webservices?

Tags: java, web-services

Is there a framework / a library that provides simple access to Yahoo's Webservices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have an API. Just click "Get an API key" [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html).

And some [examples](http://developer.yahoo.com/java/):

- [Making calls](http://developer.yahoo.com/java/howto-reqRestJava.html)
- [Parsing calls](http://developer.yahoo.com/java/howto-parseRestJava.html).